# understanding how decodeURI works

Tags: jquery, decodeuricomponent

I am trying to get the decoded value for the string. I notice that decodeURI (i am not using unescape because i read somewhere that its deprecated) works when i do a document.write(), but the alert still shows the non-decoded value.

```
var uri = "Hello&#39;s ";
var dec = decodeURI(uri);
alert(dec);
document.write(dec);
```

I finally used the below code and things worked;

```
var strName = $('<div/>').html("Hello&#39;s").text();
```

but still wondering why the original code doesn't work? It seems to be a pretty straightforward use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have misunderstood what the [`decodeURI()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI) function does.

In your example, `uri` does not contain any encoded URI data. The `alert()` still shows the HTML entities because Javascript alerts work on plaintext only. When you use `document.write()`, the browser interprets the variable and automatically parses the HTML entity (`&#39;`).

For example, here is some sample output from the JS console using your first example as a basis:

```
> var test = 'Hello&#39;s';
> decodeURI(test);
< "Hello&#39;s"
```

You are confusing HTML entities with URL-encoded characters. The URL-encoded character for `apostrophe` is actually `%27` (`&#39;` is the HTML entity).

So now, running `decodeURI()` with the unicode apostrophe replaced by the correct URL-encoded version produces the expected output. For example:

```
> var test = 'Hello%27s';
> decodeURI(test);
< "Hello's"
```

Comment: Thanks. There doesn't seem to be any native java-script method to decode HTML entities so i guess the jquery way is fine.